# Error C2280. Attempting to reference a deleted function. Getting this error when trying to delete an enemy and laser from their data structures

Tags: c++, oop

I am building my first game in C++/SDL in OOP and have come across an issue that I didn't have in my singular file version of the game.

When checking for collisions, if a collision has been detected, I am wanting the players laser and enemy ship to be destroyed from my data structure but I am getting an error that I am unable to resolve.

Error C2280. Attempting to reference a deleted function.

Without posting too much code and trying to make it easier for you to read I have included what I think is necessary. 
'CheckCollisions' is being called from the function that has the data structure holding both enemies and lasers.

Thank you.

game.cpp

```
void Game::start(Display& display, Media& media, Player& player)
{
    //Initialize SDL
    if (!display.init())
    {
        printf("Failed to initailize.", SDL_GetError());
    }
    else
    {
        //Load all media
        if (!media.load(display))
        {
            printf("Failed to load media", SDL_GetError());
        }
        else
    {
        SDL_Event e;

        std::vector<Enemy> enemies; //Holds all enemies
        std::vector<Laser> playerLasers; //Holds all of player lasers
        //std::vector<Laser> enemyLasers; //Holds all of the enemy lasers

        addEnemy(enemies); //Adds enemies to the game
        //Begin game loop
        while (!m_quit)
        {
            //Event management
            while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
            {
                if(e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
                { 
                    player.movement(e);
                }
                if (e.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
                {
                    player.shoot(playerLasers);
                }
            }

            //Movement
            player.movementBounds();
            moveLasers(playerLasers);
            moveEnemies(enemies);

            //Collision detection
            checkCollisions(player, enemies, playerLasers);

            //Render
            display.render(media, player, enemies, playerLasers);


            //Simulate 60 fps - Read on tutorial, not entirely sure if this is ok. 
            SDL_Delay(16);
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
bool Game::checkCollisions(Player& player, std::vector<Enemy>& enemies, std::vector<Laser>& playerLasers, int& enemyPos)
{

    //Check for playerLaser/Enemy collision
    for (int playerLaser = 0; playerLaser < playerLasers.size(); playerLaser++)
    {
        for (int enemy = 0; enemy < enemies.size(); enemy++)
        {
            //If collision has been detected, delete both playerLaser and Enemy
            if (findPlayerLaserCollision(playerLasers[playerLaser], enemies[enemy]))
            {
                printf("Collision");
                playerLasers.erase(playerLasers.begin() + playerLaser);
                enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + enemy);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Enemy.h

```
#pragma once

#include <SDL.h>
#include "MoveDirection.h"

struct Enemy
{
    Enemy(SDL_Rect pos, int movementSpeed, MoveDirection dir)
    {
        m_pos = pos;
        m_movementSpeed = movementSpeed;
        m_dir = dir;
    }

    SDL_Rect m_pos; //Position of enemy
    int m_movementSpeed = 0; //Movement speed of enemy
    MoveDirection m_dir; //Movement direction of enemy
    const int MIN_X_POS = 0;
    const int MAX_X_POS = 750;
};
```

Laser.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL.h>
#include "MoveDirection.h"
struct Laser
{
    Laser(SDL_Rect pos, int movementSpeed, MoveDirection dir)
    {
        m_pos = pos;
        m_movementSpeed = movementSpeed;
        m_dir = dir;
    }

    SDL_Rect m_pos; //Position of enemy
    int m_movementSpeed = 0; //Movement speed of enemy
    MoveDirection m_dir; //Movement direction of enemy
};
```

Comment: Where is the error happening? What function are you attempting to call?

Comment: Edited for more clarity, sorry.

Comment: provide line  in source code and full text of error message

Comment: @Ryan You just added more code...

Comment: The Enemy class has two const members, so assignment operator can't be generated for this class (hence the "deleted function" error happens).

Comment: Mohammad that fixed it, thank you.

Comment: @RyanSwann I'm posting it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Enemy class has two const members, so assignment operator can't be generated for this class by the compiler and is defined as deleted (hence the "deleted function" error happens).

Answer (score 1):

You start your loop with `for (int enemy = 0; enemy < enemies.size(); enemy++)` but inside the loop you call `enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + enemy);` which means that the loop index is now invalid. You started with a vector of size enemies.size() but you resized it by calling erase in your loop

Comment: Yes still looking old chap. I can't see it off hand :(

Comment: Nope. That's all I can see in the code. Good luck with it